# read file in JSON using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a JSON file returned by a server

```
{
    "myList": [
    {
        "film": "A"
    }, 
    {
        "film": "B"
    }, 
    {
        "film": "C"
    }]
}
```

And I want to display them with in React native.

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.askListing();
  }

  analyse=(responseJson)=>{
     console.log(myList);
  }


  askListing=()=>{
     var getRequest = "https://--------------");
     fetch(getRequest)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {this.analyse(responseJson)} ) 
        .catch(
          (error) => { console.error(error) }
        );
  }
```

But in my console I have :

```
Array [
  Object {
     "film": "A",
  },
  Object {
     "film": "B",
  },
  Object {
     "film": "C",
  },
]
```

1. Do you know why "Array" and "Objects" are added?
2. I want to access films name. How can I access them ? If I do console.log(myList.film) it is undefined (probably because of Array and Objects words but I also have several "film" keyword, isn't it a problem?

Comment: How do you print the object in `this.analyse`?

Comment: Is some print methods it's print also the types of the objects. What is `myList`? If it's the response array so you need to specify which object you want to get the `film` prop. For example: `myList[0].film`.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel : I changed the name of my function to be more clear, but I forgot to change a line - it is corrected now

Comment: @MoshFeu : you mean type is not added inside the variable but only when I console.log it ?

Comment: Exactly. You can try to log `JSON.stringify(responseJson)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array and Object are the type of object of class from which it is created.

> The JavaScript Array object is a global object that is used in the
>   construction of arrays
>
> The Object constructor creates the key value pairs

You need to iterate the list in order to access the films

```
for(var i=0; i < myList.length; i++)
    console.log(myList[i].film);
```

`myList.film` returns `undefined` because *film* is not a property of the list and moreover an object or a json contains a property that could be accessed using the dot operator.

Comment: @Me_Will If you find the answer useful, please [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it.